# When click on button in ajax to pass values to controller and displays back to same view page, page loads only array of loaded data

Tags: c#, ajax, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-viewmodel

The table rows are generated at page load using ajax as shown below.

```
        $.ajax({
        url: '/consultation/GetPrescHistoryList',
        type: 'POST',
        data: $('#frmPrescHistoryTable').serialize(), // it will serialize the form data
        //dataType: 'json',
        success: function (data) {

            var rowNo = 0;
            for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
                rowNo += 1;
                $("#LoadPrescHistoryTable tbody").append("<tr Class='odd gradeX'>" +
                            "<td>" + rowNo + "</td>" +
                            "<td>" + data[i].description + "</td>" +
                            "<td>" + data[i].UserName + "</td>" +
                            "<td><button type='button' class='repeat btn btn-default' data-id='" + data[i].dgid + "'>Repeat</button></td>" +
                "</tr>");
            }

            alert('LoadPrescHistoryTable has been loaded.');

        },
        error: function () {
            alert('Ajax Submit Failed ...');
        }
    }); // end ajax

    var baseUrl = '@Url.Action("GetPrescDetailsObj", "consultation")';
    $("#LoadPrescHistoryTable tbody").on('click', '.repeat', function ()                                                                                          {
        location.href = baseUrl + '?dgid=' + $(this).data('id');
    });
```

I wanted so that when i click on repeat button in the table row, the details from the chosen id will display in a label and textbox in the same page. How can i replace the location.href in order to not redirect the data, but to simply show the data that was called to the textbox and label?

```
    $('#btnPrescRepeat').on('click', function (e) {
        e.preventDefault(); // Prevent Default Submission

        $.ajax({
            url: '/consultation/GetPrescDetailsObj',
            type: 'POST',
            data: $('#frmBtnPrescRepeat').serialize(), // it will serialize the form data
            dataType: 'json',
            success: function (data) {
                $('#PHOtherInstruction').val(data.remarks);
                $('#tradename').val(data.tradename);

            },
            error: function () {
                alert("something seems wrong");
            }
        }); // ajax

    }); // #btnPrescRepeat
```

Below is the controller which is used to pass the objects back to the view, one in textbox and another in label.

```
    public ActionResult GetPrescDetailsObj(string dgid)
    {
        PrescriptionVM Prescription = new PrescriptionVM();
        PatientLookupVM Patient = new PatientLookupVM(Prescription);
        Patient.LoadDrugObj = Prescription.GetDrugObj(dgid);
        dynamic data = new
        {
            tradename = Patient.LoadDrugObj.tradename,
            remarks = Patient.LoadDrugObj.remarks

        };
        return Json(data, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);

    }
```

When i click the repeat button, the page is replaced with an array of data that i called. Can anyone please tell me what am i doing wrong?

Comment: what happens when you debug the code?

Comment: @SimonPrice sorry my bad, i did a recent add to the code and now it works, no more 404 error, just the page is replaced  with an array of data from the ajax call.

Comment: can you post some html code and are you using @html.begin form or just plain html form tag?

Comment: @sriram just plain html form tag. for the button in the table row, i didn't put any form tag. But for overall form tag i use this one `<form Class="form-horizontal" role="form" id="frmPrescHistoryTable" action="@Url.Action("GetPrescHistoryList", "consultation")" method="post">`